# how can i pass an sql query as a parameter to an other sql query in java?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

Im writing a code to manage a cafe so in the frame i added a JTable where everytime i choose an item from a JComboBox it should show in the JTable. for this purpose i added a button and for its action i made sure every time i click it, it stores the item clicked from the JComboBox in a database and then from the database its fetched in the Jtable. But the problem is that the JTable has 2 columns while the choices from the JComboBox have only one. so the other column must be called from an other database which means i have to call an sql query inside of an other one and i don't know how to do that. Ive tried the code below but it gives me this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'produit' at line 1"

b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/café", "root",
                        "ata1");

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery ( "SELECT prix FROM commande_existantes WHERE "+ cb.getSelectedItem() + "IN produit" );
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO commande_existante VALUES ('" + cb.getSelectedItem() + "'," +resultat+ ")");

    } catch (Exception a) {
        a.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    });
```

Comment: for a start you would need a space before `IN`, but I don't think you quesry makes sense anyway.

Comment: use stored procedure .your action has security issues .avoid using raw queries .in order to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @Mr.AF Why a `stored procedure` - Maybe you mean use the `PreparedStatement` class?

Comment: From the code you posted, it appears you have two database tables, one named `commande_existantes` and one named `commande_existante`, correct? What are the names and data types of the columns in those database tables?

Comment: `select prix from commande_existantes where columnA = 'selectedValue'` is the normal way to write SQL

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you want something like:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultat = 
    statement.executeQuery ( "SELECT prix FROM commande_existantes " +
                             " WHERE produit = " + cb.getSelectedItem() );
if (rs.next) {
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO commande_existante VALUES " + 
                       "('" + cb.getSelectedItem() + "'," + 
                              resultat.getDouble("prix")+ ")");
}
```

I am assuming "produit" is a column name in "commande_existantes" - so you just want to find the row(s) where the value of "produit" is the one you have selected.  In SQL, "IN" is used to find a value in a list that you specify after the "IN"... - but the query will already look at all the rows in that table looking for matches to your "WHERE" clause, so the "=" comparison is all you need.

A ResultSet potentially represents a table of values that are the answer to the query you ran - so you need to move to a row (using "next()") then get to the column value you want (in this case, using that call to "getDouble()".

You should look for an tutorial on JDBC, and in particular how to use parameters in SQL, rather than embedding the values in the SQL like you did here.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use as below:

> String selected=cb.getSelectedItem();
>
> stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO commande_existante VALUES ('"+selected+"',(SELECT prix FROM commande_existantes WHERE '"+selected+" ' IN('produit') AND ROWNUM<2 ))");